# Excel - Reference Data only once that appears multiple times

Tags: excel, google-sheets

An example of what I am trying to accomplish here:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NeKtZeMn9S_Mp0A3-10h-UMIam8kDZJ9AQj3YGv2e58/edit?usp=sharing

Goal: Create a formula that automatically fills in the State cells (Column B, Sheet1) based on transaction data from Sheet 2.

On sheet1, each city is only listed once as it's aggregate data, but on Sheet2, each city/state could be listed multiple times as there are multiple transactions.

*Note @ Mods: Please keep this tagged as "Excel" even though I'm sharing a Google Doc. I need to know how to do this in both Excel and Google Spreadsheets, but don't know how to share an online excel sheet. Thanks.*

Comment: What **exactly** is needed? Do you just want to return the state the city is in? What should be in Column B?

Comment: Yes, Column B should return the State that the city is located in, based off of data from Sheet2

Comment: Is the precise format of the first sheet required?  Could you use a pivot table to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing can be done by a simple vlookup function

```
VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$B$2:$C$10,2,false)
```